# How do I get the variable to accumulate? C++

Tags: c++

How do I get the variable total to get each price every time the program loops? The expected values is the total for every number input added together and each number has a specific value. I don't get any output when the number 8 is input, which is supposed to print and end the loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int option;
double one = 17.50;
double two = 12.95;
double thre = 11.56;
double four = 7.99;
double five = 15.00;
double six = 9.99;
double total = 0;
do{
cout<<"**************************************BRAINS!**************************************"<<endl;
cout<<"**************************************Menu**************************************"<<endl;
cout<<"1) Thalamustard-Crusted Filet - $17.50"<<endl;
cout<<"2) Hypothamoussaka - $12.95"<<endl;
cout<<"3) Amyg-DAL-a - $11.56"<<endl;
cout<<"4) CHIPpocampus & Dip- $7.99"<<endl;
cout<<"5) Pons Pasta Special - $15.00"<<endl;
cout<<"6) Medulla Frittata - $9.99"<<endl;
cout<<"7) Finish Current Sale + Start a New Sale"<<endl;
cout<<"8) Quit Forever - APOCALYPSE"<<endl;
cin>>option;}
while ( option <= 8 && option > 0);

while(option <= 0){
  if (option == 1){
    double total = total + one;
  }
  else if (option == 2){
    double total = total + two;
  }
  else if (option == 3){
    double total = total + thre;
  }
  else if (option == 4){
    double total = total + four;
  }
  else if (option == 5){
    double total = total + five;
  }
  else if (option == 6){
    double total = total + six;
  }
  else if (option == 7){
    double total = total + (total*0.06);
  }
  else{
    cout<<"HURRY UP!";
  } 
if (option == 8){
cout<<"Your total is: $"<<total; //This does not print or accumulate
}
}
}
```

Comment: Change all `double total = total + ...` to `total = total + ...`. Otherwise you're shadowing the actual accumulator `total`.

Comment: You say it doesn't print or accumulate. What does this mean? Does it print nothing at all? Or just 0? What output do you get? @cigien already found the main problem, but I think your input validation is also wrong, it will loop as long as `option` is between 0 and 8, i.e. as long as the input is valid?

Comment: The first loop will only break when invalid menu entry is input from the user. And the second loop will only run if `option` is invalid (more specifically, equal to or less than zero), and it then will run forever. Think about that logic for a while, and try to explain it to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: I'm missing something - how is this ever printing any output ever? You only exit the input loop on an input less than 1 or greater than 8, then you'll hang in the next loop if your input is less than 1. The only way to cleanly exit this program is to enter 9 or greater.

Comment: Review the `switch` statement.

Comment: OT:  If the variable doesn't change its value after assignment, declare it `const`.  This will help the compiler optimize as well as catch any unintentional writes to the variable.  For example: `const double two = 12.95;`

Comment: OT:  You could place all the prices into an array and then use the menu selection as a index into the array.  Simplifies the program.

Answer (score 4):

Every time you are creating a new local total variable in the lines

```
  double total = total + one;
```

and it is not changing the actual `total` value. Changing this line to

```
   total += one; //or two....
```

can solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

### Why your Code not working

look at the code equivalent

```
   do{
      // print measseges
      cin>>option;
   } while (option <= 8 && option > 0);

   while(option<=0){
      // decode the option meaning
   }
```

the code will circular in the first loop (*printing msg and get an input*) and exit the loop when the `option` variable greater then 8 or a nigitive value

- if first loop end with `option` is positve (*greater then 8*) then the second loop will never excuited and the program will termenate without any response !!
- the second loop will only excuit when  `option` varible is negative value ... and in this case , that will make an infinity loop >>> only the else statment will excuite for ever.

so you have **two main error** here

1. the `option` in the second loop (**if first loop termentate with negative value**)is always negative so non of your `if` statment check has meaning
2. you declare Total  variable multible times

and those problem could be solved by the follwing code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int option;
    double one = 17.50;
    double two = 12.95;
    double thre = 11.56;
    double four = 7.99;
    double five = 15.00;
    double six = 9.99;
    double total = 0;
    do {
        cout << "**************************************BRAINS!**************************************" << endl;
        cout << "**************************************Menu**************************************" << endl;
        cout << "1) Thalamustard-Crusted Filet - $17.50" << endl;
        cout << "2) Hypothamoussaka - $12.95" << endl;
        cout << "3) Amyg-DAL-a - $11.56" << endl;
        cout << "4) CHIPpocampus & Dip- $7.99" << endl;
        cout << "5) Pons Pasta Special - $15.00" << endl;
        cout << "6) Medulla Frittata - $9.99" << endl;
        cout << "7) Finish Current Sale + Start a New Sale" << endl;
        cout << "8) Quit Forever - APOCALYPSE" << endl;
        cin >> option;


        if (option == 1) {
            total = total + one;
        }
        else if (option == 2) {
            total = total + two;
        }
        else if (option == 3) {
            total = total + thre;
        }
        else if (option == 4) {
            total = total + four;
        }
        else if (option == 5) {
            total = total + five;
        }
        else if (option == 6) {
            total = total + six;
        }
        else if (option == 7) {
            total = total + (total * 0.06);
        }
        else if (option == 8) {
            cout << "Your total is: $" << total; 
            breack;
        }
        else {
            cout << "not valied input";
        }
        
    } while (option <= 8 && option > 0);

   
}
```

### code tips for better Reading

1. you could encapsulate the printing menue in another **function**
2. use `switch` statment rather than `if` it will make it much more
   cleaner to read
3. `do while` is suck use `while` loop with true condition at first
4. you coude use **array** rather than discret variable for saving constant

look for the next code it much more beautiful after apply this simple tricks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printMenu();

int main() {
    int option =0;
    double one = 17.50;
    double two = 12.95;
    double thre = 11.56;
    double four = 7.99;
    double five = 15.00;
    double six = 9.99;
    double total = 0;
    cout << "**************************************BRAINS!**************************************" << endl;
    while(option != 8) 
    {
        
        printMenu();
        cin >> option;

        switch (option)
        {
            case 1:total += one;break;
            case 2:total += two;break;
            case 3:total += thre;break;
            case 4:total += four;break;
            case 5:total += five;break;
            case 6:total += six;break;
            case 7:
                cout << "Your total is" << total << " $\n starting new sale ... \n";
                total =0;
                break;
            case 8:
                cout << "Your total is: " << total << " $ \n"<<"End of the program";
                break;

            default:
                cout << "you entered "<<option<<"and this is not a valid option please try agian\n";
                break;
        } 
    } 

}



void printMenu() {
    cout << "**************************************Menu**************************************" << endl;
    cout << "1) Thalamustard-Crusted Filet - $17.50" << endl;
    cout << "2) Hypothamoussaka - $12.95" << endl;
    cout << "3) Amyg-DAL-a - $11.56" << endl;
    cout << "4) CHIPpocampus & Dip- $7.99" << endl;
    cout << "5) Pons Pasta Special - $15.00" << endl;
    cout << "6) Medulla Frittata - $9.99" << endl;
    cout << "7) Finish Current Sale + Start a New Sale" << endl;
    cout << "8) Quit Forever - APOCALYPSE" << endl;
}
```

Comment: You could declare a `const char` array containing the menu, then use `std::cout.write()` to blast the text to the console.  First, change all those `endl` to `\n`.

Comment: The prices should be declared as `const double` since their values don't change after declaration.